# Pandas - ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). What did I miss?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a pandas dataframe that has

```
print(data['Campaign Name'])
```

will return

```
0 something
1 NaN
2 NaN
3 NaN
```

so I have a code

```
data.apply(lambda x : data['Event Code'] if data['Campaign Name'].isna() else data['Campaign Name'])
```

when I apply this function, they return me an error saying

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I am not entirely sure how they are ambiguous, as `data['Campaign Name'].isna()` will return the Series, something like

```
False
True
True
True
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call the dataframe in `apply`, call `x`. Also I expect you meant `axis=1` for row-wise calculations, not column wise:

```
data.apply(lambda x : x['Event Code'] if x['Campaign Name'].isna() else x['Campaign Name'], axis=1)
```

Also why not just use `fillna`?

```
data['Campaign Name'].fillna(data['Event Code'])
```

`fillna` fills the values that are `None` with something else... In this case the `Event Code` column.